# NextJs 5.0.0 Heroku Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, deployment, next.js

These are my scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "next build"
  },
```

This is my procfile:

```
web: npm start -- --port $PORT
```

These are my config variables:

```
NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to update `next` to `5.0.1-canary.4`** this was actually a [nextjs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) bug.